# How to delete all files in a directory except one subdirectory?

Tags: unix

I have a directory that contains multiple files and directories and i wanted to delete all the content and exclude one subdirectory; what i did was:

rm -rf * --exclude='directorytokeep'

it worked halfway throu the rm command but once it reached the directory i wanna keep it didn't go after the other files and directories.

thank you

Comment: Please show in your question what files and directories you had before your `rm` command and what remained after it and what you expected to get. Did the command print any error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please test first with

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name directorytokeep -exec echo rm -rf {} \;
```

before removing the `echo` in the command.